# How to drag Button from popover to self.view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, drag-and-drop, uipopovercontroller

i am trying to make some logic to drag the button from popover to self.view, i have two different classes one for popover in which i am making two button which comes in popover, and another class is for in which popover is appearing, when i try the dragging function in popover class it drags the button within popover but when i perform selector through delegate and send it in to 2nd class for dragging it crashes. how can i make this possible to drag the button from popover to another view?

in popover.h file i have declared
these methods:

```
   @protocol popoverDelegate <NSObject>
   -(void)multySoundRun12 : ( UIButton *)button;
  @end
```

then in popover.m file

```
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(startPoint,3,imageW,imageH)];
    [button setImage:keyBordImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(keboardButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  -( void ) keboardButtonPress:(id)sender{
      [delegate performSelector:@selector(multySoundRun12:) withObject:sender]; 
   }
```

In secondclass.h file:

```
  #import "popover.h"
 @interface mode1ViewController : UIViewController< popoverDelegate ,UIPopoverControllerDelegate >{
   UIPopoverController *popoverController;
  }
```

in secondclass.m file:

```
   -(void)multySoundRun12 : ( UIButton *)button{
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(draggedOut:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
   [self.view addSubview:button];
   }


 -(IBAction)draggedOut: (id)sender withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {
    UIButton *selected = (UIButton *)sender;
    selected.center = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
  }
```

its not working please guide me where did i go wrong? and if i am doing wrong how can i do it by right way? it makes the copy of button in the top left corner of self.view and touch ended and after it i can drag it from the top left corner of self.view, but i need to drag it in one event from its real position.

Comment: at first. in line "[delegate   addTarget:self action:@selector(..." delegate is UIViewController type. But UIViewController hasn't addTarget method.

Comment: It is wrong too. You use performSelector for call selector which requires two parameters but you does not pass anyone.

Comment: in method keboardButtonPress you need press on button which lies on the secondclass view?